# C# Deriving a class from more than one abstract class

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class

I created two abstract classes and tried to create a class that inherits from both. But I get an error message.

```
abstract class AbstractClassOne
{
    public abstract void ShowMessage();
    public abstract void DisplayName();
}

abstract class AbstractClassTwo
{
    public abstract void ShowMessage();
    public abstract void DisplayPlace();
}

class DerivedClass : AbstractClassOne, AbstractClassTwo // here under AbstractClassTwo it shows the error "cannot have multiple base classes:"
{

}
```

So a class can only derive from one abstract class?

If can derive from more than one abstract class, then what happens if both classes define the same method, as is the case above (abstract class one and two both have a method `showmessage()`, so which one will be in the derived class)?

Comment: This is what interfaces are for. You might want to look at when to use them and when not to use them.

Comment: @billz : Bcz cpp too in OOPs..so i did

Comment: @chris : yes I knw. I did the sample with interfaces for the same as above. But I read somewhere that " an abstract class with all abstract member can use same as interface". So tried to try the same with abstract classes too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple inheritance is not allowed by C# but it is allowed by C++.
To answer your question regarding the  `ShowMessage()` method that is a known problem in c++ with multiple inheritance called "The Diamond Problem". see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance

So basically you will have to excitability state to which method you are refereeing when calling it e.g.  `ParentA::ShowMessage()`

if you want to have a type that is polymorphic to 2 other types than you should create two separate interfaces and implement them. and if you want to reuse the same methods than you will have to use compositions.

**Interfaces example:**

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    public void ShowMessage();
    public void DisplayName();
}
public class ClassOne : ISomeInterface
{
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
       //implementation
    }

    public void DisplayName()
    {
       //implementation
    }
}

public class ClassTwo : ISomeInterface
{
    public void ShowMessage()
    {
       //implementation
    }

    public void DisplayPlace()
    {
       //implementation
    }
}
```

**Interface with reusable Show Message Method using composition:**

```
public class ClassTwo : ISomeInterface
{
    private ISomeInterface _MyPrivateReusableComponent = new ClassOne();

    public void ShowMessage()
    {
       _MyPrivateReusableComponent.ShowMessage()
    }

    public void DisplayPlace()
    {
         _MyPrivateReusableComponent.DisplayName()
        //implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: A doubt arise while reading ur answer. In your ClassOne and ClassTwo in interface example above, both classes are non-abstract, but u used abstract methods inside it. Cannot declare abstract members in a non-abstract class...ryt ?.

Comment: @Mortalus: Fixed a change in `DisplayPlace()` method.

Answer (score 4):

In C# it's not allowed to inherit from more than one class. To do what you want here, you need to use interfaces.

```
abstract class AbstractClassOne
{
    public abstract void ShowMessage();
    public abstract void DisplayName();
}

Interface IClassTwo
{
    void ShowMessage();
    void DisplayPlace();
}

class DerivedClass : AbstractClassOne, IClassTwo
{

}
```

Comment: Yes, I read somewhere that "an abstract class that contain only abstract methods can use same as interface". That's why I tried this way too. So I think what I read is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Arun see the link in my answer regarding the "Diamond Problem" that occurs when multiple inheritance is possible. one example is c++ that was probably what you read about.

Answer (score 2):

You can't inherit from more than one class (abstract or otherwise), but in your case the abstract classes are pretty much interfaces, so you can turn them into interfaces and inherit from them (you can inherit from any number of interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know I can use this by interface. But Why I use like this is, I read somewhere that "an abstract class that contain only abstract methods can use same as interface". So I tried this way too..

Comment: Since you tagged the question as both C# and C++, I'm guessing that what you read was about C++. In C++ there are no interfaces, but people use abstract classes because they can be used as interfaces (and C++ allows inheriting from any number of base classes). In C# you use base classes if the class really has any implementation in it, otherwise you use interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

No, abstract class whether having all abstract methods or only some, makes no difference as far as inheritance in concerned. you can inherit **only one** class (in C#) and as many interfaces as you want.